# Ubuntu dvd download not starting in other computer

Tags: downloads

I downloaded Ubuntu to DVD and then inserted DVD in other computer but nothing happens.
What am I not doing right?

Comment: can u specify "other computer"? MacOS , Windows Desktop PC with what version? Other Computer with Ubuntu installed?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the following parts :

- Did you choose CD / DVD - Rom as first boot device in your BIOS ON THE OTHER COMPUTER?
- Where did you insert the DVD ? You have to put it in the DVD Device! If not --> dead end
- Has the "other Computer" any installed OS ? If no ---> dead end
- Did you burn a bootable DVD? if not  --> dead end